# Generating classes with a loop

Tags: css, less

I have a list of colors and I want to generate classes using these colors:

**CSS**

```
@color1: #b37974;
@color2: #ffa385;
@color3: #ff5500;
@color4: #b2682e;
```

This is the code i'm using:

**Less**

```
.loopingClass(@index) when (@index > 0) {
  @ctype: "color@{index}";
  .setClass(@color,@cindex) {
    .btn-color-@{cindex} {
      background-color:@{color} ;
    }
  }
  .setClass(e(@@ctype),@index);
  .loopingClass(@index - 1);
};

.loopingClass(2);
```

When I try to compile the code with gulp, I receive **"Unrecognised input"** error. When I remove `background-color: @{color}` the error goes away. What is my mistake in this code?

**Update:**

The correct code is:

```
.loopingClass(@index) when (@index > 0) {
  @ctype: "color@{index}";
  .setClass(@color,@cindex) {
    .btn-color-@{cindex} {
      background-color:@color ;
    }
  }
  .setClass(@@ctype,@index);
  .loopingClass(@index - 1);
};

.loopingClass(2);
```

Comment: try adding background-color: @color;

Comment: Returns empty: 
.btn-color-1 {
  background-color: ;
}

Comment: Actually Swati is right and correct syntax is `background-color: @color;`. The error there is actually `e` function that you try to apply to color value which does not make any sense (in earlier Less versions `e` may remove empty value for non-appropriate values).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I already mentioned in comments above the error there is in `e` function (which does not make any sense there). The correct code would look like this:

```
@color1: #b37974;
@color2: #ffa385;
@color3: #ff5500;
@color4: #b2682e;

.loopingClass(@index) when (@index > 0) {
    @ctype: "color@{index}";
    .setClass(@color, @cindex) {
        .btn-color-@{cindex} {
            background-color: @color;
        }
    }
    .setClass(@@ctype, @index);
    .loopingClass(@index - 1);
}

.loopingClass(2);
```

In fact all this can be simplified to just:

```
@color1: #b37974;
@color2: #ffa385;
@color3: #ff5500;
@color4: #b2682e;

.loopingClass(@index) when (@index > 0) {
    .btn-color-@{index} {
        @color: "color@{index}";
        background-color: @@color;
    }
    .loopingClass(@index - 1);
}

.loopingClass(2);
```

More over the whole thing could be even more simple since you don't need to emulate arrays via "indexed variable names" because you can use array directly (unless you need to refer to those vars separately elsewhere):

```
@colors:
    #b37974,
    #ffa385,
    #ff5500,
    #b2682e;

.loopingClass(2);
.loopingClass(@index) when (@index > 0) {
    .loopingClass(@index - 1);
    .btn-color-@{index} {
        background-color: extract(@colors, @index);
    }
}
```

And finally (since I entered "optimizations never end" mode anyway), same thing with a bit of syntactic sugar:

```
@import "for";

@colors:
    #b37974
    #ffa385
    #ff5500
    #b2682e;


.btn-color- {
    .for(@colors); .-each(@color) {
        &@{i} {background-color: @color}
    }
}
```

where imported `for` is [the`for`](https://github.com/seven-phases-max/less.curious/blob/master/src/for.less).